# SAS macro functions outside of macro block or data step

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm having problems with getting the hang of using functions in SAS, the syntax is confusing.

I'm trying to get name without a date in the end. For example I have something like this: "MODEL_NAME_202101" and I want "MODEL_NAME".

I'm doing it like so.

```
%let model_ds = 
%sysfunc(
    substr(
        %scan(&models_list, 12), 
        0, 
        %length(%scan(&models_list, 12)) - 7
    )
);

%put &model_ds;
```

And only thing I get is a warring that tells me nothing about syntax errors I'm making.

```
WARNING: Argument 2 to function SUBSTR referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range.
```

No idea how I'm supposed to nest function calls. Is every call required to have `%sysfunc` before call, or nesting functions inside already called function inside `%sysfunc` are syntax correct.

Would be nice if someone could reference me to explanation/documentation of this specific "feature",  

Thanks

Comment: This seems partly bad design or at least not designed optimally for SAS. It's rare to need macro loops in SAS for one, BY group processing and DoW loops are typically faster, and data steps/call execute are incredibly powerful. Macro coding is more difficult in general.

Comment: SAS did not skip kindergarten, so it knows that counting starts from 1, not 0.

Comment: @Tom [Counting numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CountingNumber.html) is usually taught in pre-algebra; source: my child just learned them in a pre-algebra workbook.

Comment: :) https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Days-in-School-Number-Line-Routine-3973548?st=22b17f7a0c770cff514626531a7e379c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rhythm is likely correct about the best solution for you - but the specific error:

```
WARNING: Argument 2 to function SUBSTR referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range.
```

That's because of this:

```
substr(...,0,...)
```

That second argument is "what position to start from".  SAS is 1-based, not 0-based (are you a python developer originally?  This may be a bit challenging then!), so it needs to never be lower than 1.

```
substr(...,1,...)
```

Comment: Oh, I was so frustrated about the syntax I haven't noticed that SAS's indexing is starting from 1.  Nevertheless, I just don't understand how to use macro functions but thanks

Comment: @BartłomiejBłaszczyk Odds are you probably shouldn't - as Reeza points out, most SAS programming should be done without macro functions.  Consider my presentation [Writing code with your data](https://github.com/snoopy369/presentations/tree/master/Writing%20Code%20With%20Your%20Data) which shows some other ways to do things in a data-driven way without macro functions really needing to be used.

Comment: Ok, @Joe, I have tables that are meeting this name convention: "model_name_&date"  . How would you manipulate &date. to access data sets you want without functions. It's a cool idea but I'm clueless how this can be done. I'm doing it by making a variable &model_name. and &date variable and because I want to access table with the same name but from different time periods I need to strip already resolved by SAS &date variable and assign a new date. Everything about date manipulation or string manipulation is accessible with functions

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using %scan function here? Also, there is %substr, so need to use %sysfunc. See code below:

```
  %let models_list=MODEL_NAME_202101;
  %let model_ds = %substr(&models_list,1,%eval(%length(&models_list)-7));
  %put &model_ds;
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm using scan to get a name from list of names. 
Real problem was with indexing. I forgot to change it to 1 after I realized  there is no indexing from 0. 

This worked for me but I'm sure what I'm doing is weird.
```
%let model_ds = 
%sysfunc(
    substr(
        %scan(&models_list, 12), 
        1, 
        %sysfunc(length(%scan(&models_list, 12))) - 7
    )
);
```

Comment: So are you trying to apply substring on each name from list of names? If so, then you will have to apply a loop for each name extracted and then apply the substr function on it. If you can share what you have and what you want figuratively that will be helpful and easy to answer.

Comment: I have names that have &date. at the end and SAS is resolving this variable so I need to strip this date from name and attach a new date. It's quite simple and can be done in million different ways but the whole point of my question was how you can call functions outside of macro block, or data step. How does it work